# Could not renew letsencrypt certificate error 'The manual plugin is not working'

Tags: lets-encrypt

I have obtained a certificate through let's encrypt with the following command:

```
sudo certbot certonly --manual -d *.domain.com --agree-tos --no-bootstrap
--manual-public-ip-logging-ok --preferred-challenges dns-01 --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
```

When I try to renew the certificate now with `sudo certbot renew` I stumble upon the following error:

> Could not choose appropriate plugin: The manual plugin is not working;
>   there may be problems with your existing configuration.
>
> The error
>   was: PluginError('An authentication script must be provided with
>   --manual-auth-hook when using the manual plugin non-interactively.',)
>  Attempting to renew cert (domain.com) from
>   /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/domain.com.conf produced an unexpected error:
>   The manual plugin is not working; there may be problems with your
>   existing configuration.
>
> The error was: PluginError('An
>   authentication script must be provided with --manual-auth-hook when
>   using the manual plugin non-interactively.',). Skipping. All renewal
>   attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
>   /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem (failure)

Do I need to enter additional options in the command or is this feature not yet supported?

Comment: What does your host say?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem...

You don't have to renew Certificate with "*renew*" option. You have to **run the same command** you ran for Certificate creation.

It detects your Certificate needs renew, and it will ask you the new DNS record  "**_acme-challenge**" modification. You must change record as it will tell you, and continue and Voila: Certificate will renew next three months.

Comment: ok, this is what I did as my certificate was due to expire. Only problem tough was that some application (like exchange email on smartphone) were giving errors because the certificate (both private + public key) changed. Guess there is no way to circumvent this?

Comment: That's another problem, but this is a renew, the Certificate not must change, and none have to give any error because the certificate change, because Certificate not change.

Comment: You are right. It turned out I needed to install the let's encrypt certificate as root certificate on my proxy server. Now I don't experience any trouble with any applications. Thanks.